# Formally, how do I obtain $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\vec a+t\vec v)-f(\vec a)-f'(\vec a)t\vec v}{|t|}=0$ from the definition of differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, logic

Formally, how would I obtain that differentiability at $\vec a$ implies $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\vec a+t\vec v)-f(\vec a)-f'(\vec a)t\vec v}{|t|}=0$ if we define differentiability as $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $\vec a$ if and only if there exists a linear map $f'(\vec a):\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ such that $\lim\limits_{\vec h\to\vec 0}\frac{f(\vec a+\vec h)-f(\vec a)-f'(\vec a)\vec h}{\|\vec h\|}=0$?

The proposition's statement is very intuitive, since $\|t\vec v\|$ behaves exactly like $\| \vec h\|$ when both go to $0$, so the only real problem is formally showing it. Starting from the epsilon-delta definition, we have $\forall \epsilon>0; \exists \delta >0; \forall \vec h \neq \vec 0: \| \vec h \| < \delta \implies \frac{f(\vec a + \vec h) - f(\vec a) - f'(\vec a)\vec h}{\|\vec h\|}=0$, and given $\epsilon, \delta$, for any given $\vec h$ there exists $t, \vec v$ such that $t\vec v = \vec h$. This seems to set us on our way to obtain
$\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\vec a+t\vec v)-f(\vec a)-f'(\vec a)t\vec v}{\|t\vec v\|}=0$ from which we might get the desired result by multiplying both sides by $\| \vec v\|$. Unfortunately, I don't have that result yet, but only $\forall \epsilon>0; \exists \delta >0; \forall \vec h \neq \vec 0 \exists t, \vec v: \| t\vec v \| < \delta \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + t\vec v) - f(\vec a) - f'(\vec a)t\vec v\|}{|t|} < \epsilon\|\vec v\|$. How exactly do we obtain the correct quantification order and how would we finish the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$. Then, there exists a linear map $f'(\vec a)$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0; \exists \delta>0; \forall \vec h \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{\vec 0\}: 0 < \| \vec h \| < \delta \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + \vec h) - f(\vec a) -  f'(\vec a)\vec h\|}{\| \vec h \|}<\epsilon$.

Let $\vec v \in \Bbb R^n\setminus \{\vec 0\}$ be given first, and let $\epsilon > 0$ and the corresponding $\delta >0$ be given. Then: $\forall \vec h \in \Bbb R \setminus \{\vec 0\} : \| \vec h \| < \delta \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + \vec h) - f(\vec a) -  f'(\vec a)\vec h\|}{\| \vec h \|}<\epsilon$. Let $t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$ be given. Since the universally quantified $\vec h$ in the previous statement ranges over $t\vec v$, we have $\| t\vec v \| < \delta \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + t\vec v) - f(\vec a) -  f'(\vec a)t\vec v\|}{\| t\vec v \|}<\epsilon$. Notice therefore that $|t| < \frac{\delta}{\| v \|} \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + t\vec v) - f(\vec a) -  f'(\vec a)t\vec v\|}{|t|}<\epsilon\| v \|$.

We therefore obtain: $\forall v \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{ \vec 0 \};\forall \epsilon > 0; \exists \delta > 0; \forall t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}:|t| < \frac{\delta}{\| v \|} \implies \frac{\|f(\vec a + t\vec v) - f(\vec a) -  f'(\vec a)t\vec v\|}{|t|}<\epsilon\| v \|$

Now: let $v \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{ \vec 0 \}$ be given, let $\epsilon$ be given, and let $\delta^*$, be the delta that makes true: $\forall t \in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}: |t|< \frac{\delta^*}{\|\vec v\|} \implies \frac{f(\vec a + t\vec v)-f(\vec a)-f'(\vec a)t\vec v}{|t|} < (\frac{\epsilon}{\| \vec v \|})\|\vec v\| = \epsilon$. We therefore obtain our desired statement by setting $\delta = \frac{\delta^*}{\|\vec v \|}$.

We conclude $\forall \vec v \in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{\vec 0\};\forall \epsilon > 0; \exists \delta>0; \forall t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}: |t| < \delta \implies \frac{f(\vec a + t\vec v) - f(\vec a) - f'(\vec a)t\vec v}{|t|} < \delta$